# rails, image upload and resize with imagemagik

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

I made a small piece of code to upload a file and then resize it with imagemagik. I am using the system("command") function to call imagemagik to resize the image, but the output is a file of size 0 bytes. any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using RMagick, which is a ruby wrapper around imagemagick. It will help keep things more ruby-like, and is generally useful to know.

Google will help (or stackoverflow for RMagick), but the steps are something like (I'm assuming Rails 3):

in application.config:

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

Then, in your controller:

```
require 'RMagick'

def create
  @upload_io = params[:image_field]
  @filename = @upload_io.original_filename
  @filepath = Rails.root.join('public', 'images', @filename)
  File.open(@filepath) do |file|
    file.write(image_io.read)
  end

  @original = Magick::Image.read(@filepath)

  @thumbnail = @original.resize_to_fit 75 75
  @thumbnail.write(Rails.root.join('public', 'images', 'sm_' + filename)
end
```

If you're not so keen on RMagick, I would also suggest making sure you're saving your file before resizing it (does the original exist?), and make sure that your paths are consistent and that you're actually hitting the right spot on the file system.

Comment: hi... i looked at the rmagick option, but voted it out since it says its no longer maintained...

Comment: Also as far as the file paths are concerned i am sure the paths are okay, because there is a new file of size 0 bytes, so i am quite sure the command is running on the correct file. My doubt is that its the user of rails instance that is causing prblems, but even after making the folder to 777, i still get the same error

Comment: I'm using it with great success. I was unaware of it not being maintained, but it is highly functional as is. I would still say go with RMagick, and then drop down to command only if needed. But, up to you :-)

Comment: well, i read that on github... but newaz i used mini_magick, and its working damn good :) thanks